# Are Verilog directives mandatory, e.g. timescale?

Tags: verilog, directive

Is a `timescale` or any other directive mandatory in Verilog (2001) or is its use a matter of convention or style? For example, I typically use `default_nettype none` to enforce explicit net declarations throughout my implementation. However, Verilog does not require me to do so.

When it comes to `timescale`, I obviously place it at the top of my HDL testbench. But why use it in every single module of an IP? In case of inconsistent definitions, could this lead to more problems rather than preventing them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, Verilog compiler directives are not mandatory.

For `timescale`, refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 22.7 *`timescale*:

> If there is no timescale specified or it has been reset by a `resetall
> directive, the default time unit and precision are tool-specific.

The directives are global in scope, which means that when the compiler encounters one, it remains in effect for all the following code which is compiled (until another is encountered).  So, there is no need to add `timescale` directives to all your code.

However, in practice, I have seen compilers generate errors if the 1st module (or modules) compiled does not have a `timescale` directive but subsequent modules do.  These simulators also offer a command-line option to set the default timescale to avoid this error.

Comment: "[...] it remains in effect for all the following code which is compiled (until another is encountered)" -- Sounds to me ```timescale``` should be avoided in all but the top modules for ease of clarity.

Comment: @fuesika Compiler directives do not understand Verilog hierarchy, only compilation order.

Comment: @dave_59 How would I know the compilation order? Do you imply that one should rather include (the same) directive in all source files or use command-line option of the compiler to ensure a consistent timescale?

Comment: @fuesika If you write the compilation script/command then you know (or _should_  know) the compilation order. And you need to know the interaction between timescale directives and command line options. BTW, SystemVerilog removes some of these compiler order dependencies with the `timeunit` construct.

Comment: "IEEE LRM 1800-2009, section 3.14.2.3, states that it is an ERROR if some modules have timescale specified while others do not." This makes no definition in the source files the most appealing to me. Rather, timescale/timeunit would be set as command line option.